# Why doesn't my if statement return the expected result?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to make a Catchphrase style game where the user gradually clicks squares covering a picture until they can guess the person in the picture. The relevant code and comments are below:

// One of three random images to be displayed when page refreshes.

```
        var randomImage = new Array();
        randomImage[0] = "/IMAGES/0.jpg"
        randomImage[1] = "/IMAGES/1.jpg"
        randomImage[2] = "/IMAGES/2.jpg"

        var randomNumber = Math.random();

        randomNumber = randomNumber * randomImage.length;

        randomNumber = Math.round(randomNumber);

        if (randomNumber == 0) {

            document.getElementById("backPic").src="../IMAGES/0.jpg";

        }

        else if (randomNumber == 1)  {

            document.getElementById("backPic").src="../IMAGES/1.jpg";

        }

        else {

            document.getElementById("backPic").src="../IMAGES/2.jpg";

        }
```

// When user submits  their answer, if they are correct, they are alerted 'Well done!'

```
        document.getElementById("submitGuess").onclick = function() {

            var correctAnswer0 = "Terry";

            var correctAnswer1 = "Drogba";

            var correctAnswer2 = "Lampard";

            if (document.getElementById("userGuess").value == correctAnswer1 && randomNumber == 1){


                    alert("Well done!");


            }

        }
```

In the if statement above, I expect that only when submit is clicked, and userGuess is correct and randomNumber is equal to 1, that the user is alerted 'Well done'. However when the submit button is clicked when a different picture is displayed (i.e. randomImage[2]), it instead changes the picture to randomImage[1].

Can anyone help me and tell me why this isn't working?

Thank you!

Comment: I want to point out that `Math.round(randomNumber)` should be `Math.floor(randomNumber)`.

Comment: Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: *"However when the submit button is clicked when a different picture is displayed (i.e. randomImage[2]), it instead changes the picture to randomImage[1]."* Sounds to me like the button is a `type="submit"` button (either `<input type="submit" ...>` or `<button>...</button>`, note that the default type of the latter is `submit`). So the page gets refreshed with a new random number and image. But since you haven't shown us the button, we can't be sure.

Comment: Did you checked that what value you get in

document.getElementById("userGuess").value?

Comment: Need the HTML because it's essential to know what type of button/input you have and whether it's in a form tag or has a `form` attribute , etc. For all we know you could be using a bunch of divs and your use of the word "submit" is merely a "click"

Comment: Thank you all for your input! Have taken your advice on! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button submits the form and so the page gets reloaded. To avoid this, add the event parameter to your click handler function (e.g. name it `e`) and do:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

This will cancel the form submission and thus not reload the page.

Note that your code can be reduced a lot, by using a better data structure:

```js
// One of three random images to be displayed when page refreshes.
var persons = [
    {name: "Terry", img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/John_Terry_during_a_match_vs_Everton_at_Stamford_Bridge_in_2006.jpg"},
    {name: "Drogba", img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/Didier_Drogba_9248.JPG/399px-Didier_Drogba_9248.JPG"},
    {name: "Lampard", img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Frank_Lampard%2713-14.JPG/399px-Frank_Lampard%2713-14.JPG"}
];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * persons.length);
backPic.src = persons[randomNumber].img;

// When user submits their answer, if they are correct, they are alerted 'Well done!'
submitGuess.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    alert(userGuess.value == persons[randomNumber].name 
            ? "Well done!"
            : "Try again"
    );
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel form submission.
});
```

```html
<form>
<img id="backPic" width="20%" height="20%"><br>
Guess:<input id="userGuess">
<button id="submitGuess">Guess</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Trincot, 

Thank you very much for your help and effort. Your answer was fantastic, really helped me to learn something new. Thanks again!